# REGEX 8 Characters

Tags: php, regex

I need a Regex expression for PHP that finds exactly 8 characters in a string. The 8 characters have to be composed of both letters and numbers and no special characters.

EX:  A1234567 or A123456A
NOT 12345678 or AAAAAAAA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with lookaheads:

```
"/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]{8}$/i"
```

See it working online: [ideone](https://ideone.com/vRJA7)

Comment: I am fast but you are indeed faster :) +1